# Firebase Cloud function, Firestore trigger to send Cloud message,

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want the function to get the newly created document details in the collection("orders") and send the details to my admin apk with the specific token.

The error am getting:

> 9:1  error  This line has a length of 173. Maximum allowed is 80  max-len

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
admin.initializeApp();

export const onOrderCreate = functions.firestore
  .document("orders/{orderID}")
  .onCreate((change) => {
    const deviceTokens =
    "exiZaKIsSvesZ9U8_vDkXP:................-gVbwWRBJD8x8x53pc2wHrtiFYHknJs-4ixTazX_n3";
    const after = change.data();
    const payload = {
      data: {
        title: "New Notification",
        body: after.title,
      },
      token: deviceTokens,
    };
    return admin
      .messaging()
      .send(payload)
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("FCM Failed: ", error);
      });
  });
```

This is what i tried and here's the error am facing (Node.js v21.4.0).

I deploy functions running command: `npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint`

> lint
> eslint --ext .js,.ts .

> E:\My Office\01 Flock Foundation\13 Flock Ministries Android Apk\Development\Flock-App-V2\Modules\Flock Ministries FCM\functions\src\index.ts
> 9:1  error  This line has a length of 173. Maximum allowed is 80  max-len

> ✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

> node:events:497
> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
> ^

> Error: spawn npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint ENOENT
> at notFoundError (C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
> at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
> at cp.emit (C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
> at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:294:12)
> Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
> at cp.emit (C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:30:37)
> at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:294:12) {
> code: 'ENOENT',
> errno: 'ENOENT',
> syscall: 'spawn npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint',
> path: 'npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint',
> spawnargs: []
> }

> Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendOrderDetailsToAdmin = functions.firestore
    .document('orders/{orderId}')
    .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
        const orderData = await snapshot.data();
        const adminToken = 'YOUR_ADMIN_APK_TOKEN';//<--pass yours here

        
        // add all the necessary info as your req to message payload
        const message = {
            data: {
                orderId: orderData.orderId,
                customerName: orderData.customerName,//add if any thing else is needed 
            
            },
            token: adminToken,
        };

        // push the message and catch any error if encountered 
        return await admin.messaging().send(message)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log('push FCM sent successfully:', response);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error encountered while sending message:', error);
            });
    });
```